# How do I view my completed goals?

Tags: altos-adventure

Whenever I gain a level in Alto's Adventure by completing 3 goals, I'm given a new set of goals to replace the old ones.

I had one set of goals which I managed to complete without fully understanding how. I wanted to re-read my previous goals, but I couldn't find them after leveling up.

**Is it possible to view my previously completed goals? Or are they gone entirely once I've leveled up?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[As cherryblossom mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317597/181240), there is no in-game way to view previously completed goals.**

While there are some sites with incomplete goal lists, each seemed to be missing quite a few levels. I've gone ahead and combined these to create a near-complete list of goals. (Missing level 14)

> #### Level 1 goals:
>
> - Land a backflip
> - Grind a bunting line
> - Jump across a chasm
>
> #### Level 2 goals:
>
> - Travel 500m in one run
> - Catch 5 Llamas
> - Jump over 2 rocks in one run
>
> #### Level 3 goals:
>
> - Pick up a coin magnet
> - Travel 5,000m in total
> - Score 500 trick points in one run
>
> #### Level 4 goals:
>
> - Spook 15 birds in one run
> - Snowboard at night
> - Land a 2x combo
>
> #### Level 5 goals:
>
> - Pick up a hover feather
> - Land 3 backflips
> - Rip 30 bunting flags in one run
>
> #### Level 6 goals:
>
> - Stay airborne for 3 seconds
> - Travel 1,500m in one run
> - Jump over 5 rocks in one run
>
> #### Level 7 goals:
>
> - Backflip over a chasm
> - Catch 15 llamas in one run
> - Collect 25 coins in one run
>
> #### Level 8 goals:
>
> - Pick up a magnet and feather in one run
> - Ride through a village
> - Land 25 backflips in total
>
> #### Level 9 goals:
>
> - Ride through a forest
> - Wake an elder
> - Score 1,500 trick points in one run
>
> #### Level 10 goals:
>
> - Escape an elder
> - Land a double backflip
> - Backflip off a grind
>
> Unlock Maya!
>
> #### Level 11 goals:
>
> - Land 3 backflips with Maya in one run
> - Land a 3x combo
> - Pick up 50 coins with the coin magnet
>
> #### Level 12 goals:
>
> - Collect 75 coins in one run
> - Travel 2,000m in one run
> - Jump off a wooden ramp onto a grind
>
> #### Level 13 goals:
>
> - Land 2 double backflips in one run
> - Survive a rainstorm
> - Spook 30 birds in one run
>
> #### Level 14 goals:
>
> - (Unknown)
>
> #### Level 15 goals:
>
> - Backflip over a rock
> - Catch 25 llamas in one run
> - Rip 60 bunting flags in one run
>
> #### Level 16 goals:
>
> - Catch a llama while hovering
> - Land a triple backflip
> - Bounce on a rock
>
> #### Level 17 goals:
>
> - Travel 3,500m in one run
> - Score 5,000 points in one run
> - Grind 3 rooftops
>
> #### Level 18 goals:
>
> - Grind to backflip to grind
> - Land 3 double backflips in one run
> - Slide on 5 ice patches
>
> #### Level 19 goals:
>
> - Double backflip off a grind
> - Jump off a wooden ramp onto a grind 3 times in one run
> - Backflip over a campfire
>
> #### Level 20 goals:
>
> - Land 2 triple backflips in one run
> - Land a 1,000 point combo
> - Witness 3 lightning strikes
>
> Unlock Paz!
>
> #### Level 21 goals:
>
> - Smash through 3 rocks as Paz
> - Score 500 points in the first 1,000m
> - Grind during an elder chase
>
> #### Level 22 goals:
>
> - Smash 2 rocks with one boost
> - Hover over a rock
> - Land 2 backflips in a single forest
>
> #### Level 23 goals:
>
> - Kiss the rail (grind last 4m)
> - Land a 4x combo
> - Collect 125 coins in one run
>
> #### Level 24 goals:
>
> - Backflip over a sleeping elder
> - Grind for 300m in one run
> - Collect 3 super coins in one run
>
> #### Level 25 goals:
>
> - Travel 5,000m in one run
> - Backflip off a grind twice in one run
> - Jump across 5 chasms in one run
>
> #### Level 26 goals:
>
> - Smash 5 rocks in one run
> - Slide on 5 ice patches in one run
> - Spook 60 birds in one run
>
> #### Level 27 goals:
>
> - Land 10 backflips as Paz
> - Collect 5 super coins in one run
> - Escape 2 elders in one run
>
> #### Level 28 goals:
>
> - Smash a rock during an elder chase
> - Land a 5x combo
> - Backflip over 3 chasms in one run
>
> #### Level 29 goals:
>
> - Catch 6 llamas in a single village
> - Rock bounce to grind
> - Score 10,000 points in one run
>
> #### Level 30 goals:
>
> - Collect 30 coins in 10 seconds
> - Survive through rain and snow in one run
> - Land a 3,500 point combo
>
> Unlock Izel!
>
> #### Level 31 goals:
>
> - Purchase the wingsuit
> - Reach max boost speed with Izel
> - Catch 3 llamas while hovering in one run
>
> #### Level 32 goals:
>
> - Wingsuit for 200m in one run
> - Backflip to grind 3 times in one run
> - Smash 3 rocks with an ice boost in one run
>
> #### Level 33 goals:
>
> - Collect 5 coins in one wingsuit flight
> - Escape 3 elders in one run
> - Backflip over two rocks in one run
>
> #### Level 34 goals:
>
> - Land a proximity backflip
> - Perform a loop with the wingsuit
> - Travel 7,500m in one run
>
> #### Level 35 goals:
>
> - Backflip onto a rock bounce
> - Proximity wingsuit fly for 50m in a row
> - Jump across 8 chasms in one run
>
> #### Level 36 goals:
>
> - Wingsuit over a chasm
> - Land 25 backflips in one run
> - Grind for 500m in one run
>
> #### Level 37 goals:
>
> - Land a 7x combo
> - Backflip to wingsuit
> - Jump between a bunting and a roof grind
>
> #### Level 38 goals:
>
> - Grind 5 rooftops in one run
> - Survive for a full day
> - Score 35,000 trick points in one run
>
> #### Level 39 goals:
>
> - Perform 3 loops with the wingsuit in a row
> - Catch a llama while wingsuit flying
> - Fly through an archway with the wingsuit
>
> #### Level 40 goals:
>
> - Perform 3 backflips in 10 seconds
> - Backflip to grind to backflip
> - Land a 7,500 point combo
>
> Unlock Felipe!
>
> #### Level 41 goals:
>
> - Jump over 30m high with Felipe
> - Rock bounce to grind to backflip
> - Score 2,000 points in the first 2,000m
>
> #### Level 42 goals:
>
> - Double backflip over a chasm
> - Spook 20 birds while grinding in one run
> - Land a double backflip during an elder chase
>
> #### Level 43 goals:
>
> - Escape 4 elders in one run
> - Backflip over 2 sleeping elders in one run
> - Wingsuit in-between 2 separate grinds
>
> #### Level 44 goals:
>
> - Land 50 backflips in one run
> - Catch 5 lamas in 10 seconds
> - Wingsuit for 750m in one run
>
> #### Level 45 goals:
>
> - Land a 10x combo
> - Proximity wingsuit fly for 100m in a row
> - Double backflip onto a grind
>
> #### Level 46 goals:
>
> - Wingsuit over 2 chasms in one run
> - Backflip to wingsuit to grind
> - Smash 6 rocks with an ice boost in one run
>
> #### Level 47 goals:
>
> - Grind for 750m in one run
> - Collect 25 coins in one wingsuit flight
> - Stay airbone for 5 seconds
>
> #### Level 48 goals:
>
> - Backflip to rail kiss
> - Travel 15,000m in one run
> - Perform a wingsuit loop before flying through an archway
>
> #### Level 49 goals:
>
> - Catch 40 lamas in one run
> - Rock bounce to grind twice in one run
> - Proximity flip twice in one run
>
> #### Level 50 goals:
>
> - Spook 150 birds in one run
> - Land a 10,000 point combo
> - Score 75,000 trick points in one run
>
> Unlock Tupa!
>
> #### Level 51 goals:
>
> - Fall into 1 chasm as Tupa
> - Land a 13x combo
> - Escape 5 elders in one run
>
> #### Level 52 goals:
>
> - Double backflip to grind to backflip
> - Wingsuit to rock bounce
> - Land 75 backflips in one run
>
> #### Level 53 goals:
>
> - Double backflip to grind to backflip
> - Wingsuit to rock bounce
> - Land 75 backflips in one run
>
> #### Level 54 goals:
>
> - Wingsuit for 1,500m in one run
> - Score 10,000 points in the first 3,000m
> - Rip 500 bunting flags in one run
>
> #### Level 55 goals:
>
> - Double backflip to wingsuit to grind
> - Slide on 15 ice patches in one run
> - Pick up a coin magnet 4 times in one run
>
> #### Level 56 goals:
>
> - Roof Grind between two bunting grinds
> - Land a 14x combo
> - Smash 3 rocks with one boost
>
> #### Level 57 goals:
>
> - Triple backflip off a grind
> - Wingsuit in between 3 separate grinds
> - Survive for 2 days straight
>
> #### Level 58 goals:
>
> - Escape 6 elders in one run
> - Travel 30,000 meters in one run
> - Land 3 triple backflips in one run
>
> #### Level 59 goals:
>
> - Grind to rock bounce to backflip
> - Rock bounce to backflip 3 times in one run
> - Land a 15x combo
>
> #### Level 60 goals:
>
> - Catch 3 llamas in an unbroken wingsuit flight
> - Land a 15,000 point combo
> - Score 250,000 trick points in one run

#### Sources

- [Alto's Adventure Wikia - Levels and Goals](http://altosadventure.wikia.com/wiki/Levels_and_Goals)
- [AppUnwrapper - Alto’s Adventure: List of Goals for All Levels](http://www.appunwrapper.com/2015/02/20/altos-adventure-list-of-goals-for-all-levels/)
- [Keen /c /o /d /e - Alto’s adventure: goals for levels 41 to 60](http://keencod.in/?p=347)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure they are permanently (unless you reset it of course) gone once you complete them. [The wiki](http://altosadventure.wikia.com/wiki/Levels_and_Goals) has an incomplete list.